# Jquery toggle using only Link

Tags: jquery, toggle

I have written a toggle function that changes the content and image size on click and it all works fine except that I have got stuck on how to fire the toggle using only the more button.  At the moment the toggle will fire when you click anywhere within the guide box, but as I want add links in the copy but when you click on these it then closes it.

I think I can getting a bit stuck on parents, next etc

Any help would be much appreciated.

```
$(document).ready(function () {

$('.guide').click(function () {

    var text = $(this).children('.guidebox');

    if (text.is(':hidden')) {
        text.slideDown('200');
        $(this).find('.toggle').html('<< Less');                        
        //$(this).children('.myDiv2').append( $('.myDiv1>p') );
        $(".myDiv2", this).append( $(".myDiv1>p", this) );
        $(this).children('img.guideImage').animate({
            width: '412px',
            height: '275px'
          }, 500, function() {
          });   



    } else {
        text.slideUp('200');
        $(this).find('.toggle').html('More >>');
    //  $(this).children('.myDiv1').append( $('.myDiv2>p') );
        $(".myDiv1", this).append( $(".myDiv2>p", this) );  
        $(this).children('img.guideImage').animate({
            width: '198px',
            height: '132px'
          }, 500, function() {
          });   
    }

});

});
```

A demo is here
http://jsfiddle.net/ktcle/CWXqS/

Answer (score 1):

```
$('.guide a').click(function (e) {
e.preventDefault();
}
```

Add e.preventDefault()

EDIT:

I'm not sure if I understood you, but I've changed your script a bit
http://jsfiddle.net/CWXqS/1/

Answer (score 0):

Would it not be easier to have the click event on the link rather than the div with the class guide?
So changing:

```
$('.guide').click(
```

to:

```
$('.toggle').click(
```

Just remember to return false at the end of the function otherwise the browser will try to navigate away from the page or reload it as it is a hyperlink.

So for example, using the link to fire the event the script would look like this

```
$('.toggle').click(function () {

        var parentDiv = $(this).parent();
        var text = $(parentDiv).children('.guidebox');  
 //...
        return false;
};
```

Comment: unfortunately that just toggles the box now and all the other animation is lost

Comment: Yes, it would require changes to the whole script as $(this) doesn't refer to the div any more. I can post a full example of the script that works.

Comment: got it working.  I think I have Friday brain!  thanks for your help